# Integral with residues $\int_0^\infty \tfrac{\sin^2(x)}{1+x^4}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to calculate

$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{1+x^4}dx$

using method of residues. I have already seen this post, "[Integrating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x^4}dx$ with the residue theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992436/integrating-int-infty-infty-frac11-x4dx-with-the-residue-theorem)" And am integrating a quarter circle in the complex plane with a simple pole at $\exp(\frac{i\pi}{4})$. So if I put $z=e^{i\theta}, \sin^2(x)=-\frac{1}{4}(z-\frac{1}{z})$. Even so the residues are giving me difficulty. Any help would be great.

Comment: The denominator is simply $1 + z^4$; note that along the imaginary axis we have $1 + (iy)^4 = 1 + y^4$, which is precisely what allows us to use a quarter-circle contour.

Comment: @Travis So the integral would be $-\frac{1}{4}\int_C \dfrac{z-\frac{1}{z}}{1+z^4}$, where C is a quarter-circle in +i?

Comment: Almost, but note that $\sin^2 z = \frac{1}{2i} \left(z - \frac{1}{z}\right)^2 = -\frac{1}{4} \left(z - \frac{1}{z}\right)^2$ (and our integral should have a differential too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the integrand is even, so
$$
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+x^4}\,dx = 
\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+x^4}\,dx.
$$
Furthermore $\sin^2 x = \dfrac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$ so
$$
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+x^4}\,dx = 
\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+x^4}\,dx =
\frac14 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1-\cos 2x}{1+x^4}\,dx.
$$
Define a function
$$
f(z) = \frac{1-e^{2iz}}{1+z^4}.
$$
Then $\operatorname{Re}(f(x)) = \dfrac{1-\cos 2x}{1+x^4}$ for $x$ real. Let's compute $\int_C f(z)\,dz$ over the boundary of a large semi-disc: $C = \partial\{ z = x+iy : |z| < R, y = 0 \}$.

On the semi-circle (by the triangle inequality), we get
$$
|f(z)| \le \frac{1 + |e^{2iz}|}{|z|^4-1} \le \frac{2}{R^4-1}
$$
since $|e^{2i(x+iy)}| = |e^{-2y}| \le 1$ for $y \ge 0$.

The standard estimation lemma (ML-inequality) shows that
$$
\left| \int_{C_R^+} f(z)\,dz \right| \le \pi R \cdot \frac{2}{R^4-1} \to 0
$$
as $R \to \infty$. (Here $C_R^+$ is the semi-circle.)

Finally, the residue theorem shows that
\begin{align}
\int_C f(z)\,dz &= 2\pi i \big( \operatorname{Res}\limits_{\exp(i\pi/4)}(f(z)) + 
\operatorname{Res}\limits_{\exp(3i\pi/4)}(f(z)) \big) \\
&= \frac{\pi\sqrt 2}{2}\,\big( 1- \exp(-\sqrt 2)(\sin \sqrt 2 + \cos \sqrt 2) \big).
\end{align}
(Tedious algebra omitted.)

Putting everything together, and taking the real part we get $1/4$ of the above, i.e.
$$
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+x^4}\,dx = \frac{\pi\sqrt 2}{8}\,\big( 1- \exp(-\sqrt 2)(\sin \sqrt 2 + \cos \sqrt 2) \big).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your function, with $z$ in place of $x$, is symmetric in both the real and imaginary axis.

$$f(z)=\frac{sin^2(z)}{1+z^4} \longrightarrow f(x+iy) = f(-x+iy) = f(x-iy) = f(-x-iy)$$

With this in mind, try the following contours.

[image]

If you add them up, you the top and bottom should cancel (due to opposing directions of orientation), and the two horizontal strips should give you four times the value you are looking for.

Comment: Can you comment if I'm doing this right: take just the top half, we have simple poles at $\sqrt(i), -\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$ so we can just use $\frac{p(z_0)}{q'(z_0)}=\frac{sin^2(\sqrt{i})}{4\sqrt{i}^3}$, which I don't know what to do with.

Comment: What is that ratio for? What I was hinting at was using very simply the residue theorem on all four of the poles, two for each semi-circle.

Comment: The residue theorem says at a simple pole at $z_0$ where you have a function of the form (p(z)\q(z)) can be evaluated by $(p(z_0)/q'(z_0)$

Comment: Yes, that is true, and you can use that to evaluate your residues. Then you can relate them to the contour integral via the residue theorem.

Comment: Why could I not just have a contour in the first quadrant? Then I would have only 1 pole to consider and would have found my original integral.

Comment: You might, but it isn't obvious to me that the integral over the positive imaginary axis would go to zero, or some other useful value.